# Display messages in JSP, When java bean class get affected?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, javabeans

Please don't hesitate edit my question , If it is not clear.

Currently I have a situation When my `server` sends any `response`,I need to reflect the message in the `JSP` when my `bean class` changes.

My bean class will be,

```
public class Information {

    public LinkedList<String> information = null ;

    public LinkedList<String> getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(LinkedList<String> information) {
        this.information = information;
        System.out.println("List is : "+this.information);
    }


}
```

My `Thread` will be running to affect the bean class , when it get any response from the `server`

```
Class Producer extends Thread{

    LinkedList<String>() list = new LinkedList<String>();
    Information info = new Information();

    public void run() {

        if(ConnectionProtocol.protocol != null){
            try {

                response = ConnectionProtocol.protocol.receive();
                if(response != null){
                    System.out.println("Listener Response : \n"+response+"\n");
                    list.add("EventLinkEventLinkConnected event received..");
                    info.setInformation(list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to display the information in the JSP when my bean class will be affected or modified.

Also I am aware of ajax and used this situation for every 5 sec I am accessing the bean.I am getting null if there is no message in the bean.And every thing works fine.

My ajax will be,

```
function pingAction(){

    $.ajax(
            {
                type: "post",
                url: "PingAction",
                async:     true,
                data : "userId="+encodeURIComponent(userId)+"&secureKey="+encodeURIComponent(secureKey)+"&sid="+Math.random() ,
                cache:false,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
                dataType: "html",

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //alert("status :"+xhr.status+"\nthrownError : "+thrownError+"\nresponseText : "+xhr.responseText);
                xhr.abort();

            },

            success: function( responseData , status){
                //alert("PingAction Response Data : "+ responseData +"\nStatus : "+status);

                if(responseData != "null" && responseData.length != 0  && responseData != null){

                    //Process to view the response in the JSP
                }
            } ,

            complete:function(){
                timer = setTimeout(pingAction, 5000);
            }

            }                           
    );

}
```

But there is empty response coming when my server didn't send any message which is to be added in the list.Because I am calling `PingAction()` function for every 5 sec.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.